# New Redux store on incognito

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, redux, incognito-mode

I have a SPA built with React + Redux,

Some clients want to keep two instances open with different credentials (normal view + incognito view on Chrome) Since both can access the browser memory (where Redux data is being saved afaik) when user refresh the normal window this contains traces from incognito window (references, arrays, etc, redux store)

the app uses redux-persist so, by default stores everything on localStorage

Is there any way to create a proper redux store just for each incognito instance?

Comment: `Since both can access the browser memory` what memory? localStorage?

Comment: localStorage should not be shared between a normal tab and an incognito tab

Comment: @TKoL but apparently there is some data being updated on localStorage. I know should not be but it is happening and Idk if is a wrong config or a browser mistake

Answer (score 0):

My fault. Backend was mixing sessions.